# I'm trying to multiply the number of input statements by the number entered in a prior input statement

Tags: input, multiplication

```
num1=input("How many days of weather do you have?")
num1=int(num1)

j = input("What is the rainfall for day1? \n")

b = num1

    print (j * b)
```

When the user inputs the days of weather they have, I want it to produce that number of input statements, and when they put in their inputs I'll use those numbers to get the total. My problem is when I run this it just multiplies whatever the j input is by num1, I want it to multiply the number of input statements by num1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to fund the sum of the total number of days? In that case you need to add each entry.

```
num1=input("How many days of weather do you have?")
num1=int(num1)
total=0
for num in range(1,num1+1):
    j = input("What is the rainfall for day{}?".format(num))
    total+=int(j)

print (total)
```

Comment: My main goal is I want to be able to take a number from the "How many days of weather" statement, and then have it ask "How much rainfall for day_?" that number of times, while the day_ number goes up each time it asks. I hope I'm explaining this clearly.

Comment: That's exactly what my answer does.